SQL Server AG secondary database Not synchronizing
I have always on availability group configured on multiple subnets with a single database in the group. I have 1 primary and 3 secondary servers. I add 4th secondary node and it joined to cluster without errors. After about 1 hour new replica get in not synchronizing state with following errors.
SQL Server Assertion: File: <"sql\\ntdbms\\storeng\\dfs\\trans\\directlogconsumer.cpp">, line=656 Failed Assertion = 'gapMaxBlockId != 0'. This error may be timing-related. If the error persists after rerunning the statement, use DBCC CHECKDB to check the database for structural integrity, or restart the server to ensure in-memory data structures are not corrupted.

After I remove this node from the cluster my database got in suspect state. I try to re-join this node performing a full backup-restore, and it joined successfully but after about 1 hour I faced same situation.
I run SQL Server 2019 Enterprise latest CU on Windows Server 2019.
EDIT
Here is the result of stack dump
Short Stack Dump

00007FF9A2FD01DC Module(KERNELBASE+00000000000201DC)
sqllang!CStackDump::GetContextAndDump
sqllang!stackTrace
sqllang!utassert_fail_imp
sqldk!utassert_fail
sqlmin!DirectLogConsumer::GetNextLogBlock
sqlmin!HkHostCheckpointController::DoWork
sqlmin!HkHostControllerCtxtImpl::WorkLoop
sqldk!SOS_Task::Param::Execute
sqldk!SOS_Scheduler::RunTask
sqldk!SOS_Scheduler::ProcessTasks
sqldk!SchedulerManager::WorkerEntryPoint
sqldk!SystemThreadDispatcher::ProcessWorker
sqldk!SchedulerManager::ThreadEntryPoint
00007FF9A3864ED0 Module(KERNEL32+0000000000014ED0)
00007FF9A558E39B Module(ntdll+000000000007E39B)


This looks like an assertion failure. You might want to check for any anti-virus or filter drivers installed to intercept sql server activity on this 4th secondary node . Or else engage MS.

Couple of things: Is there no stack dump and trace? I would expect one in case of assertion failure. You can analyse stack trace using SQLCallStackResolver This could give you broad idea what is happening.  Other than this does this failure happen if you use empty database? The error message suggests timing issues. Is the server clock synchronising properly?

@rois server clock is in sync. I try to analyze stack dump with the tool you mention and update the question to include the results.

TBH I would start looking into opening case with Microsoft. The stack trace suggests the problem is with reading transaction log on secondary. If you Confirmed cluster is healthy, all nodes are configured the same, I don't think there is much that you can do.
